# import urllib.parse returns "ImportError:No module named parse" for jython 2.7.0

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, jython-2.7

I am using jython 2.7.0 with Java 1.7.0_45 on Windows 7.  I call my module with the following Java code

```
    try{
        python.exec("import sys");
        python.exec("sys.path.append('c:/Python')");
        python.exec("import myModule");
        python.set("var1", new PyString(remote));
        python.exec("myModule.score(var1)");
    } catch (org.python.core.PyException e) {
        System.out.println (e.toString()); 
        System.out.println ("\n");           
    }
```

The Python code for myModule.score begins with

```
import json
import urllib.parse
```

This causes the error

```
import urllib.parse
ImportError: No module named parse
```

I am suspecting this is related to Python's format changing between versions and functions becoming deprecated.  I was wondering if someone knew which version of Python jython 2.7.0 uses and what the correct syntax would be to call urllib.parse (which works fine in Python 3.5).

Comment: That works!  Thanks very much,

Comment: Glad to be of help. I have added it as an answer, in case anyone else also has similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Python 2.x [`urlparse` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) -

> The urlparse module is renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3

So you should use `urlparse` module for `Python 2.7` (Or Jython 2.7 , which would be internally using Python 2.7). You should do -

```
import urlparse
```

And use it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Jython 2.7 uses the Python 2.7 standard library.  The version number is specifically designed to correlate with the CPython version number.